# Hive cannot find LZO codec

Tags: hadoop, hive, hadoop-lzo

Error occurred when execute `select * from xxx`:

```
Failed with exception java.io.IOException:java.io.IOException: No LZO codec found, cannot run.
```

**Troubleshooting done:**

Checked hadoop-lzo.jar located in $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common for all hadoop nodes:

```
# ls $HADOOP_HOME/share/hadoop/common/ | grep lzo
hadoop-lzo-0.4.20.jar
```

Checked LZO codec configured in $HADOOP_HOME/etc/hadoop/core-site.xml for all hadoop nodes:

```
<configuration>
    ...
    <property>
        <name>io.compression.codecs</name>
        <value>
            org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodec,
            org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.DefaultCodec,
            org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.BZip2Codec,
            org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec,
            com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec,
            com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzopCodec
        </value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>io.compression.codec.lzo.class</name>
        <value>com.hadoop.compression.lzo.LzoCodec</value>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

I also tested read lzo file in mapreduce, it works correctly, so I think hadoop-lzo configured properly, but it didn't work in hive.

Comment: have you checked, the user that runs hive processes, has R-X permission on lzo files?

Comment: @KoushikRoy I checked the lzo files were not have 'x' permission, then I added 'x' permission on lzo files, but the result was the same. All of uploading files to HDFS, submitting the mapreduce job and running hive process use the same user.

Comment: This error was due to hive read wrong core-site.xml... These nodes installed with older version hadoop, and also installed with hbase, and symbol linked older version hadoop core-site.xml to hbase conf dir. As a result, hive script read the core-site.xml under $HBASE_HOME/conf/core-site.xml. And there is no configuration of lzo compression.

Comment: I see, glad it worked :)